# Quartz.net and Common.Logging - Using Log4Net

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, quartz.net, common.logging

I'm using Quartz.net within a windows service.
Currently, the trigger is not firing - I'd like to use the logging to find out why.

I have edited my config file for the windows service:

```xml
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />

    <sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<appSettings>
    <!--specific win service settings here-->
</appSettings>

<common>
    <logging>
        <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net">
            <arg key="configType" value="INLINE"/>
            <arg key="configFile" value="c:\sched.log"/>
            <arg key="level" value="INFO" />
        </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
</common>

<log4net>
    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %l - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

My file structure is as follows:

**C:\CompanyName** - root dir for all projects
**C:\CompanyName\build\bin** - Output directory for all projects / class libraries in my solution
**C:\CompanyName\lib** - Where 3rd party binaries / dlls are put

In my Windows Service project, I have a reference to Quartz (in the C:\CompanyName\lib folder)

I have also added a reference to Common.Logging.Log4net.dll

When I test my app, I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Common.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does
>   not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)":"Common.Logging,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you might have the wrong version of Common.Logging. The current version of Quartz.Net uses the Common.Logging version 1.2, not 2.0. If you need to use 2.0, try either recompiling quartz.net with the 2.0 version of common logging or try [redirecting the assembly](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/docs/2.0.0/reference/html/ch01.html#d4e45) instead.

Comment: If you redirect the binding, you'll propably need the publickeytoken, therefor, use the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\>sn -T <path-to-Common.Logging.dll>

Comment: Apparently Quartz ver 2.1.2 works with Commong.Logging Version 2.1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Use [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx) to debug the assembly loading to see if you can pinpoint the cause of the mismatch.