# Quartz.net Scheudular in MVC 3

Tags: quartz.net

Hey Friend i am using Quartz.net for scheduling jobs in mvc3 application.I wrote a sample to code to scan file in the another server. It was working fine while i was doing in my local machine. Than i published the application in my local and tested it. Till then i was working fine. But now when i deployed the application in production sever all goes in vain.

When i first create the job i can see those jobs in quartz table of cron, jobdetails and triggers has been store in mysql database. But it doesnot get scheduled. i mean if i want to do certain work to be excuted in every 5 minuted it doesn't work. And it also doesn't show any exception

I am stuck on it . Is there any way to resolve my problem. Or any configuration i need to configure for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a permissions problem.

I would suggest you to activate a logging system.
Quartz.net uses [Common.Logging](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/docs/2.1.0/reference/html/index.html) to traces errors.
You can read some more [here](http://jvilalta.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/configuring-quartznet-to-use-log4net.html) or read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9482539/219406) (Log4Net).
I have used Quartz.net + Common.Logging + NLog in the past and I've written something about it and how you can [configure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6570161/219406) it.
Should work for Quartz.net 2.x as well with some changes.

With the logging system in place you should be able to find out what happening.