# How to configure Quartz.Net version 2.1.2.0 integrated with Log4Net

Tags: web-config, log4net, quartz.net, log4net-configuration, common.logging

I have downloaded the newest version of Quartz.Net and try to configure it with common.logging and log4net dlls by using below configuration (based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481942/log4net-log-file-not-been-written-using-quartz-net-common-logging))

```
<configSections>
    <section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=2.1.2.400,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f6b8c98a402cc8a4" />
    <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging, Version=2.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>

<logging>
    <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net">
        <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />
    </factoryAdapter>
</logging>
<log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="MyQuartzLog.txt" />
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} – %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
<quartz>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="QuartzTestLog4Net" />

    <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="2" />

    <add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore, Quartz" />
</quartz>
```

It does not work.

`<section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=2.1.2.400,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f6b8c98a402cc8a4" />`

results in component loading error.  I used sn.exe to check the publickeytoken.  The keytoken is correct.

Removing the quartz sction can make the application run.   But the log object has NoOpLogger information - {Common.Logging.Simple.NoOpLogger}.

My project refers to Common.Logging version 2.1.2.0; Common.Logging.Log4Net version 2.0.0.0; and log4net version 1.2.10.0.  Are they right versions?  If not, what are the right ones.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check the sample server that comes with Quartz.NET distribution.

https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/tree/master/server/Quartz.Server

**App.config:**

It's type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"

- NameValueSectionHandler is BCL type, not Quartz.NET's
- You can probably leave out the version and public key

**Package.config**

You might have wrong packages. packages.config in sample contains working combination when using Log4Net 1.2.11

Comment: broken link, try: https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/tree/master/src/Quartz.Server