# common.logging - Redirect found in application configuration file

Tags: c#, logging, nuget, log4net, common.logging

I added common.logging.log4net to my visual studio 2012 solution via nuget.

common.logging.log4net ver. - 2.0.1
common.logging ver. - 2.0.0
log4net - ver. 1.2.10

When I build/run it locally, I see the following exception via browser:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Common.Logging' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Common.Logging' or one of its dependencies. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Common.Logging'
>   or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)]
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Common.Logging,
>   Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)]    System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +210
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +242
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +17    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +35
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +122

It is looking for Common.Logging Version=2.1.1.0, which it can't find because it is not loaded. Now when I debug the app, I see the following exception, which is a bit different:

> LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
>
> LOG: Using application configuration file:
>   C:\Workspaces\FTM\Apps\TM\TM.Web\web.config
>
> LOG: Using host configuration file:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
>
> LOG: Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>
> LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
>
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/root/e97e0952/56ab271f/Common.Logging.DLL.
>
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files/root/e97e0952/56ab271f/Common.Logging/Common.Logging.DLL.
>
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Workspaces/FTM/Apps/TM/TM.Web/bin/Common.Logging.DLL.
>
> LOG: Using application configuration file:
>   C:\Workspaces\FTM\Apps\TM\TM.Web\web.config
>
> LOG: Using host configuration file:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
>
> LOG: Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>
> LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 2.0.0.0
>   redirected to 2.1.1.0.
>
> LOG: Post-policy reference: Common.Logging, Version=2.1.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e
>
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/root/e97e0952/56ab271f/Common.Logging.DLL.
>
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files/root/e97e0952/56ab271f/Common.Logging/Common.Logging.DLL.
>
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Workspaces/FTM/Apps/TM/TM.Web/bin/Common.Logging.DLL. WRN:
>   Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
>   ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing
>   terminated.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Common.Logging'
>   or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)]
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Common.Logging,
>   Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)]    System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +210
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +242
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +17    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +35
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +122
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Common.Logging, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +12761078
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +503    System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() +142    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +334
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath) +203
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +152
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1151
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'Common.Logging, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12881540
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +159    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +12722601
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

Not sure why its trying to redirect to 2.1.1.0 (according to the logs)

Tom

Comment: maybe this post can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236772/quartz-net-and-common-logging-using-log4net

Answer (score 8):

this line I think hints at the issue:

```
LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 2.0.0.0 redirected to 2.1.1.0.
```

Check your application config file (app.config) for an assembly redirect that is telling it to attempt to load version 2.1.1.0 anytime something requests version 2.0.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run fuslogvw (fusion log viewer) to determine how a project was working and using NewtonSoft 9.0 even though there was a reference to NewtonSoft 6.0.

Another project with the same library dependency was crashing but saying it needed version 6.0 even though I couldn't find any place that 6.0 was being referenced.

It was driving me crazy.

I set the Fusion Log Viewer settings like the following so it would log all library binds:
[image: fusion log view settings]

I fired up the project and watched fusion log viewer watched.

I saw the following:

[image: fusion log viewer shows newtonsoft 6.0]

I opened that log and saw the following:

> LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application
> configuration file:
> [[ my app config ]]
> LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration
> file from
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>
> LOG: **Redirect found in application configuration file: 6.0.0.0
> redirected to 9.0.0.0. LOG: Post-policy reference: Newtonsoft.Json,**
> Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed LOG:
> GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.

I looked in app.config of the project that successfully runs (which binded to version 6. and redirected properly to 9) and I saw the following XML.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Very confusing.  But, I added that snippet into the project that was crashing because it couldn't find version 6 and the app started running perfectly.

Oy!

**Fusion Log Viewer**

If you want to try running Fusion log viewer start a Visual Studio Command prompt -- Choose x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt and you'll be able to type:

```
/> fuslogvw <ENTER>
```

Oh, you have to have admin rights to be able to configure it.  Good luck.